# How to debug Redis random resets?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis server, running from `docker-compose`, used as a backend for Python's `requests_cache` lib.

Recently, Redis started to reset itself (Reason? Maybe I have more data cached than before ~3GB).

[image]

How to debug it better? What could be the reason of what seems like random resets? Docker-compose is being run on a 64GB laptop.

My config

```
port              6379
# daemonize         no
save              60 1
bind              0.0.0.0
# tcp-keepalive     300
dbfilename        grabtracker_redis_dump.rdb
dir               /data
rdbcompression    no
loglevel          debug
```

Errors from my app:

```
{"exception": "ConnectionError(\"Error while reading from redis:6379 : (104, 'Connection reset by peer')\")", "level": "error", "ts": "2022-04-18T10:51:54.957521Z"}
{"exception": "ConnectionError('Error 111 connecting to redis:6379. Connection refused.')", "level": "error", "ts": "2022-04-18T10:51:54.978355Z"}
```

And this is Redis output (I assume it is `debug` log level already):

```
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:25.111 - DB 0: 134274 keys (0 volatile) in 262144 slots HT.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:25.111 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 3284344048 bytes in use
23:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:26.222 - RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:30.147 - DB 0: 134300 keys (0 volatile) in 262144 slots HT.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:30.147 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 3288548408 bytes in use
23:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:33.804 - RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:35.184 - DB 0: 134326 keys (0 volatile) in 262144 slots HT.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:35.184 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 3292744584 bytes in use
23:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:37.656 - RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:40.227 - DB 0: 134352 keys (0 volatile) in 262144 slots HT.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:40.227 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 3296686808 bytes in use
23:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:41.591 - RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:45.265 - DB 0: 134379 keys (0 volatile) in 262144 slots HT.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:45.265 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 3300440688 bytes in use
23:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:49.294 - RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:50.302 - DB 0: 134404 keys (0 volatile) in 262144 slots HT.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:50.302 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 3304628600 bytes in use

1:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.862 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.862 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.862 # Configuration loaded
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.862 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.863 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.863 # Server initialized
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.867 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.6
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.867 * RDB age 40919 seconds
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:51:55.867 * RDB memory usage when created 3081.22 Mb
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:53:08.319 # Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 133932, keys expired: 0.
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:53:08.319 * DB loaded from disk: 72.455 seconds
1:M 18 Apr 2022 10:53:08.319 * Ready to accept connections
```